# dropdown menu using html and css is showing dropdown items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown menu using HTML and CSS only. I do not wish to use any script for it. The menu simply doesn't show on hover.

```
.td_menu_item:hover, .td_filter_item:hover, .td_product_container:hover {background-color: #E6E6E6;}
.td_menu_item {  position: relative; display: inline-block;}
.dropdown_menu_items a:hover, .dropdown_menu_items a{background-color: #ddd; color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;}
.dropdown_menu_items { display: none;position: absolute;background-color: #f1f1f1;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);z-index: 1;}

<td class= "td_menu_item"> Menu Item 
                  <div class="dropdown_menu_items">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                  </div>
</td>
```

I want to be able to hover on Menu Item and see dropdown links only on hover. It's not showing the dropdown links at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.td_menu_item:hover .dropdown_menu_items {
    display: block;
}
```

---

Full example:

```css
.td_menu_item:hover, 
.td_filter_item:hover, 
.td_product_container:hover {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.td_menu_item {
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown_menu_items a:hover,
.dropdown_menu_items a{
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown_menu_items {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.td_menu_item:hover .dropdown_menu_items {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class= "td_menu_item"> Menu Item 
      <div class="dropdown_menu_items">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It worked after adding your code to mine. But the dropdown menu is showing abnormal size visually. When I hover over "Menu Item" it shows me the dropdown items right sticking to one another. When I hover over the dropdown items, then they show the padding. Making it visually unpleasing. Can you point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's nothing in the code you posted. As you can see in the snippet in my answer, the padding is present with and without hovering the menu items.